# Connection to CloudBees database using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, cloudbees

I've just uploaded my locally developed app to CloudBees. It works fine: I can load the web pages and it can access the database.

However, I cannot connect to its database (also provided by CloudBees) using MySQL Workbench or the command line tool. It always says

Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ec2-50-19-213-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (10060)

Any CloudBees configuration that I might be missing?

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/11/how-to-accesspopulate-cloudbees-mysql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there were some firewall problems in the corporate router that prevented me from connecting before. I tried at home and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

double check your database connection parameters using SDK : `bees db:info -p <databasename>`
you should be able to connect to DB using mysql workbench and other mysql tools.

Answer (score 0):

In the MySQL forum exists a collection of links for [various types of connections using MySQL Workbench](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,252640,252640#msg-252640). One is probably especially interesting for you as it deals with [Amazon RDS databases](http://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/). Among others it shows what connection parameters are needed.